# Why does comparing 2 .NET framework classes with eachother result in a stackoverflow exception?

Tags: c#, reflection, json.net, stack-overflow

**Problem**

I'm currently working on creating an application. In this application I was working with serializing a Func. This somehow crashed my application without an exception.

Crashing without an exception made me curious on wtf is going on so I did some deep diving and after some digging finally found out that somewhere within Newtonsoft.Json a `List.Contains` is happening which is then executing an equals check on 2 properties.

Apparently in this equals check results in an infinite loop which causes a stackoverflow exception.

**Reproducing the issue with just C#**

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> expr = (t) => t.Length;
Func<string, int> exprCompiled = expr.Compile();

var aa = exprCompiled.Method.Module;
var bb = exprCompiled.Method.Module.Assembly;

//This code results in either an infinite loop or a Stackoverflow Exception
var tempresult = aa.Equals(bb);

Console.WriteLine("This code is never executed");
```

**Reproduce the issue with Newtonsoft.Json**

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> expr = (t) => t.Length;
Func<string, int> exprCompiled = expr.Compile();

//This code results in either an infinite loop or a Stackoverflow Exception
var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exprCompiled);

Console.WriteLine("This code is never executed");
```

**Actual underlying issue**

Doing a bit more digging into how the .NET framework works I think the issue is with the implementation of the `InternalAssemblyBuilder` internal class and the `InternalModuleBuilder` internal classes. Both of them have an Equals method override like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj is InternalAssemblyBuilder)
    {
        return this == obj;
    }
    return obj.Equals(this);
}
```

I think it should be this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj is InternalAssemblyBuilder)
    {
        return this == obj;
    }
    return base.Equals(this); //changed obj to base
}
```

Comment: Isn't a `Func` basically a pointer to a function/address?  If you store it, then it may not be correct next time you load it (memory addresses may move around).

Comment: Even if it might not work I don't think a Stackoverflow exception should be thrown when you compare 2 C# objects with eachother.

Comment: Undefined behaviour results in undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @Neil Comparing the 'Module' and 'Assembly' instances of a Lambda expression's method is not an undefined behavior. It should return false.

Comment: @Devedse, you can avoid those json and serialization related stuff as they dont have anything to do with this. Question will get better attention with only relevant information. This is a good question.

Comment: @MatJ I changed the title, still wanted to leave some background in though to avoid people saying: "Why do you do this? Don't do this, bye"

Comment: I'd say it is definitely a bug. And looking at the [implementation and comment of the `GetHashCode` methods](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#086b3c2942de83b3) in both of the classes shows that whoever was implementing these classes had no idea what they were doing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in your question's **Actual underlying issue** as well as by [NineBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101087/nineberry) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929372/why-does-comparing-2-net-framework-classes-with-eachother-result-in-a-stackover/54933695#comment96625921_54929372), Microsoft's implementations of [`InternalAssemblyBuilder.Equals(object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/assemblybuilder.cs,f830bb8f5aed9ee8,references) and [`InternalModuleBuilder.Equals(object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/modulebuilder.cs,01ead99de3ce5a15,references) appear to be broken.  Specifically, in the case of checking equality between an object of type `InternalAssemblyBuilder` and an object of type `InternalModuleBuilder`, an infinite recursion will occur.

To work around this issue you can set a custom `IEqualityComparer` on [`JsonSerializer.SettingsEqualityComparer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_EqualityComparer.htm) that substitutes plausible implementations of `Equals()` for these types.  The following is one such example using reference equality:

```
public class CustomJsonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer
{
    public static readonly CustomJsonEqualityComparer Instance = new CustomJsonEqualityComparer();

    // Use ImmutableHashSet in later .net versions
    static readonly HashSet<string> naughtyTypes = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder",
        "System.Reflection.Emit.InternalModuleBuilder"
    };

    static readonly IEqualityComparer baseComparer = EqualityComparer<object>.Default;

    static bool HasBrokenEquals(Type type)
    {
        return naughtyTypes.Contains(type.FullName);
    }

    #region IEqualityComparer Members

    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        // Check reference equality
        if ((object)x == y)
            return true;
        // Check null
        else if ((object)x == null || (object)y == null)
            return false;

        var xType = x.GetType();
        if (xType != y.GetType())
            // Types should be identical.
            // Note this check alone might be sufficient to fix the problem.
            return false;

        if (xType.IsClass && !xType.IsPrimitive) // IsPrimitive check for performance
        {
            if (HasBrokenEquals(xType))
            {
                // These naughty types should ONLY be compared via reference equality -- which we have already done.
                // So return false
                return false;
            }
        }
        return baseComparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return baseComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you would use it as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    EqualityComparer = CustomJsonEqualityComparer.Instance,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exprCompiled, settings);
```

Notes:

- You may need to tweak `CustomJsonEqualityComparer.HasBrokenEquals()` if other `System.Reflection.Emit` types have similarly broken implementations of `Equals()`.
- It might be sufficient to ensure that the two incoming objects have the same `System.Type` value for `GetType()`, as the broken `Equals()` methods discovered so far only overflow the stack in the event that two *different* types are compared, and both have the same bug.
- While I was able to reproduce the infinite recursion and verify it has been fixed using some mockup objects, I was unable to confirm that Json.NET can actually serialize your `Func<string, int> exprCompiled`.